# What does "quotable" mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

> Afters years of being one of the most quotable political operatives around, I developed a case of political laryngitis.

All quotable's meanings have to do with putting something in between quotation marks, making excerpts, citing and repeating. None of these feel right in the context of this sentence.

To mean, quotable in this sentence probably mean to be trusted. But I do see how the meaning "worth quoting" can fit here, somewhat.

Anyways, I am not quite sure. My command of English is pretty bad.

Comment: I take the usage here to mean ***most easily quoted***- I.e., when talking to the media they say things in a way that makes them memorable and easily understood so that people discussing the same topic later on will tend to use his wording.

Comment: If you glance through some of [Google Books' claimed 57 written instances](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he+is+very+quotable%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) of ***he is very quotable***, I'm sure the intended sense will soon become clear. It's not something likely to be said in isolation, so most of those citations will probably feature additional text saying much the same thing in different words.

Answer (score 2):

See [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quotable) or [Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary (1913)](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=quotable&use1913=on):

> *quotable*
>
> Capable or worthy of being quoted; as, a quotable writer; a quotable sentence.

And, for what it is worth, the quality of your question and reasoning would tell me your English is rather good, certainly not "pretty bad."